# retrive text in a website table by corresponding value in the same row- selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Forgive me if I'm asking this question wrong. I'm new to selenium/web-related programming and definitely don't have a good grasp on website structure/query/etc.

I'm using selenium to do some stuff, and after a few days I've (well, mainly with the help of some lovely people on this site) managed to make my script work. The script involved submitting an order, and now the last thing I need to do is get the number associated with that order.

At the end of my current script, I'm redirected to the show order form website (you have to be logged in to see it but I added a screenshot down below) and I want to know the order number for the order I just submitted. Each order will be associated with a unique name (i.e. bobcat, crystal, etc.- doesn't look unique now because I was testing but will be). I made it so that the name would be reflected in the show order page (in the submit step there is no place for a name but I just added it as a note), and now I want to use that name to obtain the order 
ID (which is under the OrderID column).

So my question is, how can I find the string under the 'OrderID' column (i.e. 'recover.dummy@gmail.com-01082015-151052'), if the only thing I know is the name that's associated with the order (i.e. 'harold')?

The page source for the table and the screenshot are at the bottom.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The script will be run repeatedly, creating orders as they are requested by clients. So I can't find my answer based on location on page, as orders will be continuously be added.

[image: show order page]

```html
<div class='boxbody'>

<table>
    <tr class="header_row">
        <th class='header_row noborder orderid'>Order ID</th>
        <th class='header_row noborder pordered'>Products Ordered</th>
        <th class='header_row noborder pcomplete'>Products Complete</th>
        <th class='header_row noborder pstatus'>Status</th>
        <th class='header_row noborder pnote'>Note</th>
    </tr>


    <tr class="oddrow">
    <td class="oddrow"><a href="/ordering/status/recover.dummy%40gmail.com-01082015-151052/">recover.dummy@gmail.com-01082015-151052</a></td>
    <td class="oddrow" id='26910_total_ordered'></td>
    <td class="oddrow" id='26910_finished'></td>
    <td class="oddrow">Ordered</td>
    <td class="oddrow">harold</td>
    </tr> 

    <tr class="evenrow">
    <td class="evenrow"><a href="/ordering/status/recover.dummy%40gmail.com-01082015-145743/">recover.dummy@gmail.com-01082015-145743</a></td>
    <td class="evenrow" id='26907_total_ordered'></td>
    <td class="evenrow" id='26907_finished'></td>
    <td class="evenrow">Complete</td>
    <td class="evenrow">bobcat</td>
    </tr> 

    <tr class="oddrow">
    <td class="oddrow"><a href="/ordering/status/recover.dummy%40gmail.com-01082015-145449/">recover.dummy@gmail.com-01082015-145449</a></td>
    <td class="oddrow" id='26906_total_ordered'></td>
    <td class="oddrow" id='26906_finished'></td>
    <td class="oddrow">Complete</td>
    <td class="oddrow"></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr class="evenrow">
    <td class="evenrow"><a href="/ordering/status/recover.dummy%40gmail.com-01082015-145034/">recover.dummy@gmail.com-01082015-145034</a></td>
    <td class="evenrow" id='26905_total_ordered'></td>
    <td class="evenrow" id='26905_finished'></td>
    <td class="evenrow">Complete</td>
    <td class="evenrow"></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr class="oddrow">
    <td class="oddrow"><a href="/ordering/status/recover.dummy%40gmail.com-01082015-143913/">recover.dummy@gmail.com-01082015-143913</a></td>
    <td class="oddrow" id='26902_total_ordered'></td>
    <td class="oddrow" id='26902_finished'></td>
    <td class="oddrow">Complete</td>
    <td class="oddrow">bobcat</td>
    </tr> 


</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it by xpath using [`find_element_by_xpath()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath):

```
name = 'harold'
order_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="boxbody"]//table//tr[td[last()][text()="%s"]]/td[1]/a' % name)
print order_id.text
```

Here we are checking the text in the last `td` inside a `tr` and if there is a match, we are getting the `link` from the first `td` inside the same `tr`. Hope this is clear.

Comment: incredible, thank you! I'm manipulating that line to attempt to understand the whole xpath thing (and also retrieve additionally variables besides the link, while I'm at it), but I'm not quite there. I thought it basically meant: go to the boxbody class --> table --> tr tag where the text of last td tag (aka the name) matches the string --> find the first td tag (aka the link) of that same tr with the matching td. But when I try to obtain the # products/ status/ other info by just replacing the td[1]/a with td[2]/a, td[3]/a, etc.,...

Comment: ...I get errors. Is this because the first td tag was <a href=link..., while the others are IDs and plain text? Sorry for all the questions, I just want to be sure I understand what's going on. And I'm just now seeing your explanation below the code you posted, so sorry if comment pt 1 is redundant.

Comment: nevermind :). I found it by taking the /a off the end. Thanks again for all of your help today. you rock!